# Misplaced 'votes' button on profile page

Tags: bug, design

The buttons for the different tabs on the Activity part of your personal profile page are aligned perfectly fine if you have no recent activity:

[image: everything fine]

but as soon as you have new reputation changes, responses, ..., the line is too wide and the 'votes' button is displayed on the next line. Further, the 'votes' button *follows* your cursor movement: If you move the cursor over the 'tags' button, you'll see this:

[image: ugly line break]

If you move the cursor over the 'answers' button, then 'votes' will be displayed below 'questions'.

I could reproduce this issue with a recent version of Chrome (45.0) and Firefox, both on Win7.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: a little more complicated than that.  the "votes" button is under whichever button is to the right of the last underline, and if you move your cursor over to the right along the line of buttons, the "votes" button moves too, finally dropping down under the first item, yet another line farther down.  a bit confusing, but i'm guessing intentional.

Comment: This was already reported in Apr 2015 with the update of the site design (see [Site design updates are live!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6073/5764)) and has not been fixed.